# Is Cache Invalidation on S3 a One Time Event or a Type of Policy?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a set of files on Amazon S3 cloudfront that I do not want cached.  I was able to create an Invalidation on a single file that seemed to work.  However, going forward the file seems to be cached again even though the Invalidation Entry is still present.  Is the Invalidation a "One Time Event"?  Does anyone know the exact details of how this works.

I would like a set of files to basically never be cached going forward.

Thanks for any suggestions and best practices advice.

Answer (score 1):

Invalidation removes a cached entry from CloudFront's edge locations, but has no impact on whether or not the invalidated object(s) are cached again in the future. All else held equal: after you issue an invalidation, objects that were previously cached will be cached again on subsequent requests.

Before we explore the options, two definitions that are important to understand:

- **Cache behaviors** are effectively routes with dedicated configurations applying only to requests matching the route (known as a path pattern)
- **Cache policies** are instructions for how CloudFront will cache your responses. Cache policies are attached to one or more cache behaviors. The min and max TTL set a floor and ceiling on the value returned in your Cache-Control/Expires headers. The default TTL determines the length of time to cache a response when you don't provide a Cache-Control/Expires header.

Do you want to prevent caching for all files in your S3 bucket?
Attach the **CachingDisabled** cache policy (provided by CloudFront) to your default cache behavior.

Do you want to prevent caching for only certain files in your S3 bucket?

- If the files you do not want to cache live in the same directory, create a cache behavior  to match that path and use the **CachingDisabled** cache policy (provided by CloudFront) to prevent files in that directory from being cached. This instructs CloudFront to use a cache policy that does not cache responses when processing requests that match a specific path/route.
- Set a `Cache-Control` header as metadata on the objects in S3 to instruct CloudFront not to cache, while caching the other objects.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html (Scroll down to **Adding headers to your objects using the Amazon S3 console**)